# host WPF windows in another WPF window

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

here is my problem: i have created a main window called mainWindow in XAML (vb.net) and inside i have 2 buttons (valid and stop) and a grid in the center.
I have two others little windows (valid window and stop window) written in XAML (vb.net) which have buttons, textbox...

I want, when i click on valid button or stop button, display the valid window or the stop window  inside the grid of my mainWindow, so i have this code in my mainWindow.vb:

```
enter code here

Private Sub valid_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles valid.Click
        Dim content As Object = valid_.Content /*Classe valid_ (a window in xaml)*/
        valid_.Content = Nothing
        Me.Grid.Children.Add(content)
    End Sub

    Private Sub stop_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles stop.Click
        Dim content As Object = stop_.Content
        stop_.Content = Nothing
        Me.Grid.Children.Add(content)
    End Sub
```

So when i click on button valid in my mainWindow, it's ok it displays the valid window in my grid.

First problem: then when i click on button stop in my mainWindow, the stop window is placed just above the valid window, it is not nice, is there a way to clear the grid before display this second window?

And finally, the biggest problem: i need to click many times on valid button or stop button but when i click the second time i have a null reference exception: Me.Grid.Children.Add(content) content is null after the first call so i am only able to click one time on my button.

How can i fix it in order to click many times on my buttons please?
I give you thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Yet again, someone writes some invalid code and then says *why isn't this code working*? If you look at your code, you should see something:

```
Private Sub valid_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles valid.Click
    Dim content As Object = valid_.Content /*Classe valid_ (a window in xaml)*/
    Me.Grid.Children.Add(content)
End Sub
```

I'm guessing that you have a private variable for your `Valid Window` as you call it: `valid`. On this line, what are you doing to your variable?:

```
valid_.Content = Nothing
```

That's right! You're setting its `Content` property to `null`. Therefore, I'm not really sure why you were surprised that it was `null` after the first attempt.

> *How can i fix it in order to click many times on my buttons please?*

Try removing the line that sets the `Content` property to `null`.

---

UPDATE >>>

Your problem is *really* caused by the fact that you cannot display any UI element in two places at once. Your whole idea of copying the `Window.Content` to your `DataGrid` is entirely wrong, but in the name of brevity, your fix is simply to move your content back to the `Window`, rather than setting it to `null` each time. Try something like this:

```
Private Sub valid_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles valid.Click
    If Me.Grid.Children.Count > 0 Then           'Put content back where it belongs
        Dim oldContent = Me.Grid.Children(0)
        stop.Content = oldContent
        Me.Grid.Children.Remove(oldContent)
    EndIf
    Dim content As Object = valid_.Content /*Classe valid_ (a window in xaml)*/
    valid_.Content = Nothing
    Me.Grid.Children.Add(content)
End Sub
```

Please forgive any code mistakes, as I don't write VB.NET. Also, you'll need to update your other method likewise.

Comment: No it is impossible to do what you say because when i delete this line it is impossible to click one time on the button, i have an error:Specified element is already the logical child of another element

Comment: Please learn how to program before you start announcing that something is impossible. Your problem is really caused by the fact that you cannot display any UI element in two places at once. However, you should *not* be trying to move the content from one Window to another anyway. Instead, you should be declaring templates and having the Framework regenerate your content each time it is displayed.

Comment: Your solution works but of course it is not nice, how about if i have 10 buttons...I suppose this is for this reason you are talking about template. Can you show me your other solution with template please?

Comment: Let's be clear about this... this *not so nice* solution is *yours*. I've told you that you should not be doing it this way. Furthermore, to find out *How to use `DataTemplate`s to alternate control display?*, you would need to ask another question. Here on Stack Overflow, we ask one specific question per post. As this answer has answered the specifics of *this* question, you should now [mark it as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and ask a new question. You *could* provide a link to this question from your new question to provide some context.

Comment: I would like to accept your answer but i don't see any button to do this on this webpage...

Comment: You should see an up arrow above a number (0 at the moment) above a down arrow above a tick icon to the left of the answer. Click the tick to accept the answer... it should go green when you do.